# Is it worthwhile to write a wrapper for calling Julia or Python functions from emacs?

Tags: elisp, python, functions

For writing efficient emacs functions, would it be worthwhile/not too difficult to write a C wrapper for calling Julia functions or for calling Python functions via Numba/pycc?

For reference: *Julia* is a higher-level language designed for scientific computing that contains cfunction, a routine for efficiently passing Julia functions to C functions that accept function pointers. From what I gather, these functions are called more or less as efficiently as a native C function is called. Julia also happens to be able to call functions in many other languages very efficiently. *Numba* is a just-in-time compiler for Python that can also create C libraries using the command *pycc*. Both Julia and Python/Numba approach C-level performance for many tasks.

Comment: I suspect that unless you write a proper (read: persistent) bridge, any performance gains will be dwarfed by the time you need to boot up a process running the foreign code.  So, please write a small demo first, then measure, then decide what approach to follow.

Comment: This appears to be multiple questions wrapped into one.  Please separate out the question about lisp speed, the discussion about Julia and/or Python, and the question about wrappers to external programs.

Comment: I separated out the speed question. Most of the discussion about Julia is background for the primary question, so I am keeping it but making clear that it is subordinate to the question. Is that good?

Comment: wasamasa: as I made more clear in the my edits to the second paragraph, I am talking about languages with specific methods of creating C-callable functions as machine code.

Comment: You are aware that there is no FFI in Emacs?  The closest thing to this is the relatively recent module support which requires you to write a dynamically loaded library in the same style of C as the core of Emacs is written in.

Comment: I was hoping to write a Lisp primitive that handled the function calling:

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Writing-Emacs-Primitives.html

Comment: I am actually wrong about Julia: unlike pycc, I don't think it makes machine code. Making an efficient bridge is documented online, however.

Comment: Worth it for what? It's uncommon to perform heavy-duty numerical computation within Emacs.